# Duplicated search engine results

Tags: bug, google, seo

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to report this but I've been noticing that Google gives me the exact same page twice in some search results...
[image]

This has happen more than once and now I've decided to report it...
The two page links are:

[Setting up SSL for Google Cloud Storage static website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759710/setting-up-ssl-for-google-cloud-storage-static-website)

and

[Setting up SSL for Google Cloud Storage static website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759710/setting-up-ssl-for-google-cloud-storage-static-website/22767544)

Not sure why that number in the end but the pages are exactly the same....
My search was "google cloud storage static website ssl"